# Color ramp as Value for Strength input on Emission shader

Tags: node-editor, emission

I am trying to plug the Color Ramp output to the Strength input of an Emission shader which gives me the noise randomnesss as intended. However, color ramps seem to be operating within the range of 0-1 (black-white), meaning that my Emission max value is 1.

The problem is, I would like my max Strength value to be 20 units, or higher than 1.
How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: The math node set to multiply OR map range node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Color Ramp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/color/color_ramp.html) node can output values outside the [0...1] range, but you have to manually input the values inside the field though. The limit of 1 is a soft limit and you can't go below 0.

[image]

I just noticed I plugged the color ramp into the Color input of the Emission node, but it works the same way if you plug it into the Strength input, because the color is automatically converted to a float value.

For better usability you can plug a [Math](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/math.html) node set to Multiply between the color ramp and the emission node.

[image]

If you're only going to use 2 grayscale stops on your color ramp, you'll have a better time using a [Map Range](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/map_range.html) node.

[image]

The From Min and From Max inputs are like the two stop positions on the color ramp axis. The To Min and To Max are equivalent to the stop color values.

Another solution that's more relevant to your problem :

[image]

You can set the color ramp stop's color to the emission color and plug the output into the color input of the emission. You can then tweak the emission strength directly.

Comment: Wow.. I never knew that limit was soft! Personally, I would prefer a multiply, though.. that could really trip me up if I went back to it later.

Comment: @RobinBetts Agreed ! I added a bit more info about that topic

Comment: +1 for readability in the node group, you'll notice in the first gif the color represented in the colorramp node never changes from 1.0 white.  You'd have to click in to see.